# Using the quotient rule to find $f'$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{6x}{5 \ln(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Below is a problem and the process by which the first derivative is found:

[image: Quotient Rule]

I used the quotient rule but did not get the same result. Can someone explain this to me?

Here is what I got after using the quotient rule:

[image: My result]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide your calculations so we can help find the error?

Comment: As far as I can see, no tricks were used in your instructor's derivation, and there are no errors. So the answer to the question of how is 'by applying the quotient rule correctly.'

Comment: I just made the edit to my question.

Comment: Sorry, could you walk me through that?

Comment: @Brandon Cornelio: First derivative OK. Second derivative needs work.

Comment: Awesome! I understand how he simplified it. Thank you. @Morgan Rodgers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is the same as your professor's. $\frac{30\ln{x} - 30}{(5\ln{x})^2} = \frac{30\ln{x} - 30}{25(\ln{x})^2} = \frac{6\ln{x} - 6}{5(\ln{x})^2}$. Splitting the numerator and simplifying slightly, we get $\frac{6}{5(\ln{x})} - \frac{6}{5(\ln{x})^2} = \frac{6}{5}\left((\ln{x})^{-1} - (\ln{x})^{-2}\right)$.

Just because answers look different doesn't mean they are. If your answer looks different from someone else's, you should compare your steps against theirs, not assume that one answer is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was confused about how he simplified it. I appreciate the detailed response!

Comment: @BrandonCornelio A word of advice, for future reference: you probably would have gotten more helpful responses if you'd singled out the step your professor took that you didn't understand (e.g., "how did my professor get from step 3 to step 4?").

Comment: I'll be sure to be more clear in any future questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the same result with minor mistake

Your result should be -

$\frac{30\ln x - 30}{(5\ln x)^2}$

$=\frac{30\ln x - 30}{25(\ln x)^2}$

$=\frac{6\ln x - 6}{5(\ln x)^2}$

$=\frac{6\ln x}{5(\ln x)^2} - \frac{6}{5(\ln x)^2}$

This is same what your professor is getting.